# question about link for updated app on app store

Tags: iphone, itunes

when you update an application on the app store. does the previous link now link to the updated app or does there exist 2 separate applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link your app is assigned when it is approved and hits the iTunes App Store is the only link that app will be assigned. If you were to update your app 50 times, the link will still be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be the former, cause it usually links to the most recent version of the application, especially since the system (itunes, app store and all) is overall designed to prompt you to update if you're not at the latest version, so it's no wonder this is so.

Answer (score 0):

The link is always the same. When you update an app the latest version is always displayed on the page.